# Ubuntu not booting 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, acer

After installing ubuntu on fresh computer it is not bootting, Boot-Repair did not help, all I get is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13122708/

Answer (score 1):

**Reinstall the GRUB boot loader** to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

**Boot from the Ubuntu installation media** - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sda
    update-grub
```

`sda` = disk | `sda1` = efi partition | `sda2` = system partition | (taken from your pastebin output)

To re-check the partition numbers use **GParted** - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

**Boot into BIOS** of the PC - **select Ubuntu** in **UEFI settings** to be the **default system to boot**.

Note : What is this sdb1 partition ? All boot loaders have to be installed to the same partition !

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling grub,

- Boot into a Ubuntu Live/USB or CD.
- Setup a Chroot Environment

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi

  sudo chroot /mnt
  ```
- Reinstall grub

  ```
  grub-install
  exit
  ```

NOTE: the above commands are for the OP only. Here's a comprehensive guide on [repairing/restoring grub](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/#rescue_grub).